# Vertical size height of inline-block to max without wrapper block

Tags: html, css

[>My sample code at jsfiddle<](http://jsfiddle.net/7uKmX/3/)

1. I want to justify the height of blocks in same lines, i.e. visual margin must be the same.
   Which way we can do that?
2. If it's possible, I want to make width of blocks to 100% ONLY if it's sinle block in line (if container block's width < 2*min-width of children blocks). The second wish describes why I wantn't to use wrapper)

Any ideas?

oops, corrected link!

Comment: Yes and no - i cant really follow you.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with pure css. You're going to have to use javascript